# Retrofit Post Token&Param

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

**url**:http://xxx.xxx.xxx/Order/Interface/V1/Polling?token=xxx&param={"user":{"userID":2}}

post

```
token＝"xxx"
param＝"{"user":{"userID":2}}"
```

How to use Retrofit Post?

Answer (score 0):

POST request parameters are not typed in the URL, they are typed on the body. For a request like that, you must use a GET request.

Comment: In order to better demonstrate my problem, so I write.

url:http://xxx.xxx.xxx/Order/Interface/V1/Polling   post parameter  token & param

Comment: Here you have the official Retrofit2, with many examples: https://square.github.io/retrofit/